# Transfer raw binary with apache commons-net FTPClient?

Tags: java, ftp, binary-data, apache-commons-net

**UPDATE: Solved**

I was calling `FTPClient.setFileType()` **before** I logged in, causing the FTP server to use the default mode (`ASCII`) no matter *what* I set it to. The client, on the other hand, was behaving as though the file type had been properly set. `BINARY` mode is now working exactly as desired, transporting the file byte-for-byte in all cases. All I had to do was a little traffic sniffing in wireshark and then mimicing the FTP commands using netcat to see what was going on. Why didn't I think of that two days ago!? Thanks, everyone for your help!

I have an xml file, utf-16 encoded, which I am downloading from an FTP site using apache's  commons-net-2.0 java library's FTPClient. It offers support for two transfer modes: `ASCII_FILE_TYPE` and `BINARY_FILE_TYPE`, the difference being that `ASCII` will replace line separators with the appropriate local line separator (`'\r\n'` or just `'\n'` -- in hex, `0x0d0a` or just `0x0a`). My problem is this: I have a test file, utf-16 encoded, that contains the following:

`<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-16'?>`
`<data>`
    `<blah>blah</blah>`
`</data>`

Here's the hex:
`0000000: 003c 003f 0078 006d 006c 0020 0076 0065  .<.?.x.m.l. .v.e`
`0000010: 0072 0073 0069 006f 006e 003d 0027 0031  .r.s.i.o.n.=.'.1`
`0000020: 002e 0030 0027 0020 0065 006e 0063 006f  ...0.'. .e.n.c.o`
`0000030: 0064 0069 006e 0067 003d 0027 0075 0074  .d.i.n.g.=.'.u.t`
`0000040: 0066 002d 0031 0036 0027 003f 003e 000a  .f.-.1.6.'.?.>..`
`0000050: 003c 0064 0061 0074 0061 003e 000a 0009  .<.d.a.t.a.>....`
`0000060: 003c 0062 006c 0061 0068 003e 0062 006c  .<.b.l.a.h.>.b.l`
`0000070: 0061 0068 003c 002f 0062 006c 0061 0068  .a.h.<./.b.l.a.h`
`0000080: 003e 000a 003c 002f 0064 0061 0074 0061  .>...<./.d.a.t.a`
`0000090: 003e 000a`                                                            `.>..`

When I use `ASCII` mode for this file it transfers correctly, byte-for-byte; the result has the same md5sum. Great. When I use `BINARY` transfer mode, which is not supposed to do anything but shuffle bytes from an `InputStream` into an `OutputStream`, the result is that the newlines (`0x0a`) are converted to carriage return + newline pairs (`0x0d0a`). Here's the hex after binary transfer:

`0000000: 003c 003f 0078 006d 006c 0020 0076 0065  .<.?.x.m.l. .v.e`
`0000010: 0072 0073 0069 006f 006e 003d 0027 0031  .r.s.i.o.n.=.'.1`
`0000020: 002e 0030 0027 0020 0065 006e 0063 006f  ...0.'. .e.n.c.o`
`0000030: 0064 0069 006e 0067 003d 0027 0075 0074  .d.i.n.g.=.'.u.t`
`0000040: 0066 002d 0031 0036 0027 003f 003e 000d  .f.-.1.6.'.?.>..`
`0000050: 0a00 3c00 6400 6100 7400 6100 3e00 0d0a  ..<.d.a.t.a.>...`
`0000060: 0009 003c 0062 006c 0061 0068 003e 0062  ...<.b.l.a.h.>.b`
`0000070: 006c 0061 0068 003c 002f 0062 006c 0061  .l.a.h.<./.b.l.a`
`0000080: 0068 003e 000d 0a00 3c00 2f00 6400 6100  .h.>....<./.d.a.`
`0000090: 7400 6100 3e00 0d0a`                                        `t.a.>...`

Not only does it convert the newline characters (which it shouldn't), but it doesn't respect the utf-16 encoding (not that I would expect it to know that it should, it's just a dumb FTP pipe). The result is unreadable without further processing to realign the bytes. I would just use `ASCII` mode, but my application will also be moving *real* binary data (mp3 files and jpeg images) across the same pipe. Using the `BINARY` transfer mode on these binary files also causes them to have random `0x0d`s injected into their contents, which can't safely be removed since the binary data often contains legitimate `0x0d0a` sequences. If I use `ASCII` mode on these files, then the "clever" FTPClient converts these `0x0d0a`s into `0x0a` leaving the file inconsistent no matter what I do.

I guess my question(s) is(are): does anyone know of any good FTP libraries for java that just move the damned bytes from there to here, or am I going to have to hack up apache commons-net-2.0 and maintain my own FTP client code just for this simple application? Has anyone else dealt with this bizarre behavior? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

I checked out the commons-net source code and it doesn't look like it's responsible for the weird behavior when `BINARY` mode is used. But the `InputStream` it's reading from in `BINARY` mode is just a `java.io.BufferedInptuStream` wrapped around a socket `InputStream`. Do these lower level java streams ever do any weird byte-manipulation? I would be shocked if they did, but I don't see what else could be going on here.

EDIT 1:

Here's a minimal piece of code that mimics what I'm doing to download the file. To compile, just do

```
javac -classpath /path/to/commons-net-2.0.jar Main.java
```

To run, you'll need directories /tmp/ascii and /tmp/binary for the file to download to, as well as an ftp site set up with the file sitting in it. The code will also need to be configured with the appropriate ftp host, username and password. I put the file on my testing ftp site under the test/ folder and called the file test.xml. The test file should at least have more than one line, and be utf-16 encoded (this may not be necessary, but will help to recreate my exact situation). I used vim's `:set fileencoding=utf-16` command after opening a new file and entered the xml text referenced above. Finally, to run, just do

```
java -cp .:/path/to/commons-net-2.0.jar Main
```

Code:

(NOTE: this code modified to use custom FTPClient object, linked below under "EDIT 2")

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.zip.CheckedInputStream;
import java.util.zip.CheckedOutputStream;
import java.util.zip.CRC32;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.*;

public class Main implements java.io.Serializable
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Main main = new Main();
        main.doTest();
    }

    private void doTest() throws Exception
    {
        String host = "ftp.host.com";
        String user = "user";
        String pass = "pass";

        String asciiDest = "/tmp/ascii";
        String binaryDest = "/tmp/binary";

        String remotePath = "test/";
        String remoteFilename = "test.xml";

        System.out.println("TEST.XML ASCII");
        MyFTPClient client = createFTPClient(host, user, pass, org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.ASCII_FILE_TYPE);
        File path = new File("/tmp/ascii");
        downloadFTPFileToPath(client, "test/", "test.xml", path);
        System.out.println("");

        System.out.println("TEST.XML BINARY");
        client = createFTPClient(host, user, pass, org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
        path = new File("/tmp/binary");
        downloadFTPFileToPath(client, "test/", "test.xml", path);
        System.out.println("");

        System.out.println("TEST.MP3 ASCII");
        client = createFTPClient(host, user, pass, org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.ASCII_FILE_TYPE);
        path = new File("/tmp/ascii");
        downloadFTPFileToPath(client, "test/", "test.mp3", path);
        System.out.println("");

        System.out.println("TEST.MP3 BINARY");
        client = createFTPClient(host, user, pass, org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
        path = new File("/tmp/binary");
        downloadFTPFileToPath(client, "test/", "test.mp3", path);
    }

    public static File downloadFTPFileToPath(MyFTPClient ftp, String remoteFileLocation, String remoteFileName, File path)
        throws Exception
    {
        // path to remote resource
        String remoteFilePath = remoteFileLocation + "/" + remoteFileName;

        // create local result file object
        File resultFile = new File(path, remoteFileName);

        // local file output stream
        CheckedOutputStream fout = new CheckedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(resultFile), new CRC32());

        // try to read data from remote server
        if (ftp.retrieveFile(remoteFilePath, fout)) {
            System.out.println("FileOut: " + fout.getChecksum().getValue());
            return resultFile;
        } else {
            throw new Exception("Failed to download file completely: " + remoteFilePath);
        }
    }

    public static MyFTPClient createFTPClient(String url, String user, String pass, int type)
        throws Exception
    {
        MyFTPClient ftp = new MyFTPClient();
        ftp.connect(url);
        if (!ftp.setFileType( type )) {
            throw new Exception("Failed to set ftpClient object to BINARY_FILE_TYPE");
        }

        // check for successful connection
        int reply = ftp.getReplyCode();
        if (!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(reply)) {
            ftp.disconnect();
            throw new Exception("Failed to connect properly to FTP");
        }

        // attempt login
        if (!ftp.login(user, pass)) {
            String msg = "Failed to login to FTP";
            ftp.disconnect();
            throw new Exception(msg);
        }

        // success! return connected MyFTPClient.
        return ftp;
    }

}
```

EDIT 2:

Okay I followed the `CheckedXputStream` advice and here are my results. I made a copy of apache's `FTPClient` called `MyFTPClient`, and I wrapped both the `SocketInputStream` and the `BufferedInputStream` in a `CheckedInputStream` using `CRC32` checksums. Furthermore, I wrapped the `FileOutputStream` that I give to `FTPClient` to store the output in a `CheckOutputStream` with `CRC32` checksum. The code for MyFTPClient is posted [here](http://gist.github.com/459095) and I've modified the above test code to use this version of the FTPClient (tried to post a gist URL to the modified code, but I need 10 reputation points to post more than one URL!), `test.xml` and `test.mp3` and the results were thus:

```
14:00:08,644 DEBUG [main,TestMain] TEST.XML ASCII
14:00:08,919 DEBUG [main,MyFTPClient] Socket CRC32: 2739864033
14:00:08,919 DEBUG [main,MyFTPClient] Buffer CRC32: 2739864033
14:00:08,954 DEBUG [main,FTPUtils] FileOut CRC32: 866869773

14:00:08,955 DEBUG [main,TestMain] TEST.XML BINARY
14:00:09,270 DEBUG [main,MyFTPClient] Socket CRC32: 2739864033
14:00:09,270 DEBUG [main,MyFTPClient] Buffer CRC32: 2739864033
14:00:09,310 DEBUG [main,FTPUtils] FileOut CRC32: 2739864033

14:00:09,310 DEBUG [main,TestMain] TEST.MP3 ASCII
14:00:10,635 DEBUG [main,MyFTPClient] Socket CRC32: 60615183
14:00:10,635 DEBUG [main,MyFTPClient] Buffer CRC32: 60615183
14:00:10,636 DEBUG [main,FTPUtils] FileOut CRC32: 2352009735

14:00:10,636 DEBUG [main,TestMain] TEST.MP3 BINARY
14:00:11,482 DEBUG [main,MyFTPClient] Socket CRC32: 60615183
14:00:11,482 DEBUG [main,MyFTPClient] Buffer CRC32: 60615183
14:00:11,483 DEBUG [main,FTPUtils] FileOut CRC32: 60615183
```

This makes, basically zero sense whatsoever because here are the md5sums of the corresponsing files:

```
bf89673ee7ca819961442062eaaf9c3f  ascii/test.mp3
7bd0e8514f1b9ce5ebab91b8daa52c4b  binary/test.mp3
ee172af5ed0204cf9546d176ae00a509  original/test.mp3

104e14b661f3e5dbde494a54334a6dd0  ascii/test.xml
36f482a709130b01d5cddab20a28a8e8  binary/test.xml
104e14b661f3e5dbde494a54334a6dd0  original/test.xml
```

I'm at a loss. I *swear* I haven't permuted the filenames/paths at any point in this process, and I've triple-checked every step. It must be something simple, but I haven't the foggiest idea where to look next. In the interest of practicality I'm going to proceed by calling out to the shell to do my FTP transfers, but I intend to pursue this until I understand what the hell is going on. I'll update this thread with my findings, and I'll continue to appreciate any contributions anyone may have. Hopefully this will be useful to someone at some point!

Comment: Wow, that's weird. I checked the source code for `BufferedInputStream` and `SocketInputStream` (at least the Java part) and I don't see anything that could be changing the bytes around like that. I'd suggest making a copy of `FTPClient` and changing the input stream hierarchy to `CheckedInputStream(BufferedInputStream(CheckedInputStream(SocketInputStream())))`, and use the checksums to see if you can identify where the bytes are being changed. That would be useful information to have in the question. (Even better, put your test code online and link to it)

Comment: Also, +1 for a well-written question ;-)

Comment: I will try this; thank you. I had never heard of CheckedInputStream. Very cool!!

Comment: Has anyone else (e.g. here) tried to reproduce this yet?

Answer (score 34):

After login to the ftp server

```
ftp.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
```

The line below doesn't solve it:

```
//ftp.setFileTransferMode(org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
```

Comment: Thanks, this did it for me. Strange that text mode would be default.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds to me as if your application code might have got the selection of ASCII and BINARY mode inverted.  ASCII is coming through unchanged, BINARY performing end-of-line character translations is the *exact opposite* of how FTP is supposed to work.

If that is not the problem, please edit your question to add the relevant part of your code.

**EDIT**

A couple of other possible (but IMO unlikely) explanations:

- The FTP server is broken / misconfigured.  (Can you successfully download the file in ASCII / BINARY mode using a non-Java command-line FTP utility?)
- You are talking to the FTP server via a proxy that is broken or misconfigured.
- You've somehow managed to get hold of a dodgy (hacked) copy of the Apache FTP client JAR file.  (Yea, yea, very unlikely ...)

Comment: It would seem that way, but I've run the code at least 5 times and removed as many variables as possible. I edited my post to include code that I have verified recreates the issue. Unfortunately I can't offer an ftp site from which to download the file, so hopefully you have access to one (I am just testing on localhost). Thanks for the reply, and I'd appreciate it if you have any thoughts to share!

Comment: I've considered the first case you mention as the most likely explanation if the code is all correct. It's a pretty default install of proftp on Ubuntu. I just tried downloading with the standard ftp command line client and the xml file comes through fine (this is, somewhat, to be expected since the client is probably using ascii mode, which did transfer the xml correctly with FTPClient). It also transfers the mp3 file correctly (same md5sum), so it doesn't look like it's the server, unless the FTPClient is connecting to it with different settings than the cmd line client (a possibility).

Comment: Also, I'd upvote you for your help but I don't have 15 rep points yet! :)

Answer (score 3):

I found that Apache retrieveFile(...) sometimes did not work with File Sizes exceeding a certain limit. To overcome that I would used retrieveFileStream() instead. Prior to download I have set the Correct FileType and set the Mode to PassiveMode

So the code will look like

```
    ....
    ftpClientConnection.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
    ftpClientConnection.enterLocalPassiveMode();
    ftpClientConnection.setAutodetectUTF8(true);

    //Create an InputStream to the File Data and use FileOutputStream to write it
    InputStream inputStream = ftpClientConnection.retrieveFileStream(ftpFile.getName());
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(directoryName + "/" + ftpFile.getName());
    //Using org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils
    IOUtils.copy(inputStream, fileOutputStream);
    fileOutputStream.flush();
    IOUtils.closeQuietly(fileOutputStream);
    IOUtils.closeQuietly(inputStream);
    boolean commandOK = ftpClientConnection.completePendingCommand();
    ....
```