# Java FTP xls file upload

Tags: java, file-upload, ftp, ftp-client, apache-commons-net

I am trying to upload files to a FTP Server in a Java class.
I use apache library: org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.
The upload function works fine until I try to upload a XLS (Excel) file.
In particular, when I upload it, the file is uploaded, but it seems to be corrupted. In fact its size is different from the original size and when I try to open it, it doesn't open correctly and doesn't show all the data.

Here is a portion from the code I use:

```
FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
File[] fileList;fileList = localFilePath.listFiles();
for (File file : fileList) {
    String fileName = file.getName();
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
    ftpClient.storeFile(fileName, fileInputStream);
    fileInputStream.close();
}
```

Thank you very much for any kind of help.

Answer (score 4):

I solved the problem using the suggestion in this thread:

[Transfer raw binary with apache commons-net FTPClient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145768/transfer-raw-binary-with-apache-commons-net-ftpclient)

All I needed to do was setting binary file mode for non .txt files:

```
if (fileExtension.equals("txt")) {
    ftpClient.setFileType(FTPClient.ASCII_FILE_TYPE);
} else {
    ftpClient.setFileType(FTPClient.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Also, as a side note, you can access those constant directly from the class FTP instead of FtpClient...